# How can I get URI from ApexCharts with React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, react-router, apexcharts

I am trying to get the chart URI by using the Data URI method. I've seen a bunch of examples using Apexchart Js to get pdf like [this CodePen from ApexChart](https://codepen.io/apexcharts/pen/JjPZPNb), when trying to reproduce it on react I got  **TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined**

Here is my component did mount look like this:

```
componentDidMount() {

console.log(this.state.loading);
if (this.state.loading === false) {
  const {options} = this.state;
  const node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
  if (node instanceof HTMLElement) {
    var chart = new ApexCharts(node.querySelector('.charty'), options);
    chart.render().then(() => {
      setTimeout(function() {
        chart.dataURI().then(uri => {
          console.log(uri);
        });
      }, 4000);
    });
  }
} else {
  return;
}
}
```

Type is defined as well in my state and in the render like so :

```
    <div className='rfe'>
      <div className='rfea'>
        From {this.state.AxisMonth[0]} to{' '}
        {this.state.AxisMonth[this.state.AxisMonth.length - 1]}
      </div>
      <Chart
        className='charty'
        type='area'
        options={this.state.options}
        series={this.state.series}
        width='1000'
        height='380'
      />
    </div>
  </div>
```

here is the error I got

[image]

Really need help with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `exec` function to call any method of ApexCharts from a React component.

```js
 getDataUri() {
    ApexCharts.exec("basic-bar", "dataURI").then(({ imgURI, blob }) => {
      console.log(imgURI);
    });
  }
```

Here's a full [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-datauri-stackoverflow-60110892-iryeq) example